# Plugin in Android for Jquerymobile

Tags: android, plugins

I want to create a plugin that can be used with jquery mobile.Is it possible to do so.If it is could anyone guide me in this matter

Comment: http://the-jquerymobile-tutorial.org/jquery-mobile-tutorial-CH09.php

Comment: thanks for info  but is it possible to create plugin in android and use in jquery moblie

Comment: What do you mean create in Android? jQM is just HTML, CSS, and javascript, so your plugin should use the same...